# How do I add checkbox filters to my Posts index page (Rails app)

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a Rails app that has many Posts. Each Post has different parameters, two of these parameters are zagat_status and michelin_status. (it's a restaurant discovery website).

I'm trying to add 2 checkboxes that allow me to filter results for:

a) zagat_status .. so clicking the checkbox shows all Posts where zagat_status is "Yes" 
b) michelin_status .. so clicking the checkbox shows all Posts where michelin_status = "1", "2", or "3"

Moreover, I want these two checkboxes to be able to work with each other. So if I click both, both filters apply simulatneously.

However, this is not working... how do I get the code below to work??

**POST MODEL**

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
   scope :zagat_status, -> (zagat_status) { where zagat_status: zagat_status }
   scope :michelin_status, -> (michelin_status) { where michelin_status: michelin_status }

   validates :name, presence: true
   validates :city, presence: true
   validates :address, presence: true

   def self.search(query)
     where("name like ? OR city like ? OR address like ?", "%#{query}%", "%#{query}%", "%#{query}%")
   end

end
```

**POST CONTROLLER**

```
class PostsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_post, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  # GET /posts
  # GET /posts.json
  def index
    @posts = Post.all
    if params[:search]
      @posts = Post.search(params[:search]).order("created_at DESC")
    elsif params[:zagat_status].present?
      @posts = Post.zagat_status(params[:zagat_status]).order("created_at DESC")
    elsif params[:michelin_status].present?
      @posts = Post.michelin_status(params[:michelin_status]).order("created_at DESC")
    else
      @posts = Post.all
    end
  end

  private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_post
      @post = Post.find(params[:id])
    end

    # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
    def post_params
      params.require(:post).permit(
        :name,
        :michelin_status,
        :zagat_status,
        :address,
        :city,
        :cuisine,
        :neighborhood,
        :price_range,
        :longitude,
        :latitude)
    end
end
```

**INDEX.HTML.ERB FILE (for POSTS)**

```
  <div class="search-filter">
        <form>
          <span>Accolades</span>
          <div class="accolades-panel">
            <label>
              Michelin Star(s) <dd>1,2,3 and bibs</dd>
              <input type="checkbox" name="michelin_status" value="1">
            </label>
            <label>
              Zagat<dd>rated</dd><input type="checkbox" name="zagat_status" value="Yes">
            </label>

          </div>
        </form>
      </div>
```

**INDEX.JS.ERB FILE**

Blank

**INDEX.JSON.JBUILDER FILE**

```
json.array!(@posts) do |post|
  json.extract! post, :id, :name, :zagat_status, :michelin_status, :cuisine, :address, :city, :price_range, :longitude, :latitude
  json.url post_url(post, format: :json)
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code doesn't work because the results are returned immediately after one of the conditions in the controller are satisfied e.g. if params[:search] exists it will return:

```
@posts = Post.search(params[:search]).order("created_at DESC")
```

And the rest of the code won't be run, because it's inside elsif blocks.

Something like this should work:

```
@posts = Post.all
if params[:search]
  @posts = @posts.search(params[:search]).order("created_at DESC")
end
if params[:zagat_status].present?
  @posts = @posts.zagat_status(params[:zagat_status]).order("created_at DESC")
end
if params[:michelin_status].present?
  @posts = @posts.michelin_status(params[:michelin_status]).order("created_at DESC")
end
```

This way we build the query based on the existence of parameters. However this is not the most elegant solution.

I would suggest you create a method in your model that would take in the parameters, and then create a query there based on the parameters.

Comment: thanks, but it's still not working..   i added my JSON file above, maybe that helps?

Comment: It's not working in what way? Do you get any errors? What does your development/testing log show?

Comment: my development log does not show anything at all when i check/uncheck the filter.. its as if the check/uncheck is somehow not being submitted to the server..

Comment: Do you have an event handler on the checkbox that triggers the controller action?

Comment: i don't think so - the only relevant code is that which i have pasted above in my question.  what code do i need to add to trigger the event?

Comment: Well currently your form doesn't submit anything read more about form creation here:

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/form_helpers.html



And if you want to submit it via ajax (in which case you can put the event handler on the checkboxes so that information is updated instantly), you can put remote: true on the form.

More about that here:

http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/working_with_javascript_in_rails.html

Comment: i tried replacing the form in in my index page with this:    <%= form_tag do %>

            <%= check_box_tag(:zagat_status) %>
            <%= label_tag(:zagat_status, "Zagat status") %>

      <% end %>   it still doesn't work